# ORA-20900: Directory MY_DIR does not exist or no privileges

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm logged-in into AWS RDS Oracle instance with **master account**.

I'm able to create a new directory and write file under directory. but i could not list and read file under directory.

### Query to list file under directory

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(rdsadmin.rds_file_util.listdir(p_directory => 'MY_DIR'));
```

### Query to read file under directory

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
(rdsadmin.rds_file_util.read_text_file(
    p_directory => 'MY_DIR',
    p_filename  => 'rice.txt'));
```

I'm getting following error while running above mentioned queries.

```
**ORA-20900: Directory MY_DIR does not exist or no privileges**.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.RDS_SYS_UTIL", line 158
ORA-06512: at "SYS.RDS_SYS_UTIL", line 176
ORA-06512: at "RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL", line 42
```

This error is coming with RDS
Oracle engine ="**oracle-ee-cdb**" only,

it is working fine with Oracle engine "oracle-ee".

Comment: Compare the privileges you have on the two 'engines'; sounds like one had both WRITE and READ, and the error is because the other only has WRITE?

Answer (score 1):

after giving read, write privilege to **RDSADMIN** on respective directory resolved this issue.

```
GRANT READ,WRITE ON DIRECTORY MY_DIR TO RDSADMIN;
```

Comment: My import was failing so wanted to check the log file in the dir.
Stack:
1. SQLDeveloper;
2. Oracle Standard Edition Two (CDB);

Example:
1. EXEC rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.create_directory(p_directory_name => 'product_descriptions');  // WORKS!
2. SELECT * FROM TABLE(rdsadmin.rds_file_util.listdir(p_directory => 'PRODUCT_DESCRIPTIONS'));  //NOT WORKING:  ORA-20900: Directory PRODUCT_DESCRIPTIONS does not exist or no privileges** 

FIX:
GRANT READ,WRITE ON DIRECTORY MY_DIR TO RDSADMIN;

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about "AWS RDS Oracle".

However, error you got means that user - which is trying to use directory named `MY_DIR` - doesn't have privileges on it.

In a "normal/simple/ordinary/everyday" Oracle database (such as 11gXE on my laptop) (and not "AWS RDS Oracle"), this is how it works:

- `SYS` creates directory, Oracle database object which points to a filesystem directory
- `SYS` **grants** `read`/`write` privileges on that directory to user which will be using it (for example, `SCOTT`)
- `SCOTT` is now able to access the directory and read/write files in it

Looks like you're missing step#2 - there are no privileges granted to you.

Comment: OWNER              TABLE_NAME         PRIVILEGE          TYPE                                                                                                
SYS                    MY_DIR                   READ                   DIRECTORY                                                                                                                         
SYS                    MY_DIR                   WRITE                  DIRECTORY